# What are different types of notifications in iOS and how to configure them correctly?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, silent-notification

When I read [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html), they mention 3 types of notification: local, remote, and silent.

Local notification can be inferred from its name, that is sent by the app locally.

However, what is the difference between the other two types?

Comment: NOTE: Apple docs have renamed _silent_ notification to _background_ notification!

Comment: I beleive the title of this question should be changed to something like 'what are different types of notifcations in iOS and how to configure them correctly?'

Answer (score 226, accepted):

**EDIT:** While this answer is fully applicable, there are some *additions* (not changes) to notifications in iOS 12. I highly recommend watching [WWDC 2018: What’s New in User Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/710) and read [this amazing and must read article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/09/preparing-your-app-for-ios-12-notifications/).

Main changes are:

- grouped notifications along with summary format
- provisional notifications ie show notifications directly in notification center without user permission
- critical notifications which ignore 'do not disturb' or 'mute'
- ability to interact with the notifications in the extensions
- ability to completely reset or update actions
- ability to deeplink into app's notification Settings from phone's Notification Center

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Not sure since when but from the Apple docs, the 'silent notification' has been **renamed** to 'background notification'

There are too many settings that need to be set right for it to work. I'll try to dissect them and make them easier to understand.

Overall, several things are important.

- the overall difference between a *silent* and *user* notification
- different types of *user* notifications
- how a remote notification, i.e. the *payload*, is configured from your server
- how to enable push notifications and remote notifications from background modes on your project
- how to register your token with APNs for *remote* and *silent* notifications and APNs architecture
- how to request permission for *user* notifications
- enabling 'background app refresh' and 'notifications' from the **device**
- what is `content-available`
- understanding that the iOS is *upstream* to your app when it comes to receiving a remote notification
- what happens when the OS receives notifications when the app has been user-terminated
- A note on reliability and APNs architecture

---

I highly recommend everyone to watch the first 7 minutes of: [WWDC 2015: What's new in Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720). From there, the presenter mentions that there are 2 major types of notifications:

## Silent Notifications

They happen in the background, hence you never see any alert/badge/sound. Things get downloaded *without* you knowing about them.

> **iOS 11 bug**

> See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11).
> iOS 11 initial releases were buggy for silent notifications. Make sure
> you have the latest version for your testing, otherwise, it may not
> work

---

## User Notifications

[image]

As the name says, it has something to do with the *user*. That is, the user will see an alert/badge or hear a sound. It has 2 types.

**Local Notifications**

A Local Notification can be *triggered* in 3 different ways:

- `UNLocationNotificationTrigger`:
  You see an alert when you're close to a Walmart store.
- `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`: e.g. You see an alert every 10 minutes.
- `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` like December 1st 1:00PM 2017.

**Remote Notifications**

They are similar to local notifications but they are triggered from the server, e.g. a WhatsApp message that has a From field (Mom) and a body field (I love you!).

## Token registration and APNs architecture:

To receive a silent or remote notification, you need to register for a token using:

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

<sub>Registering does NOT require user permission. This makes silent notifications to become seamless. See [this moment of the WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720?time=142)</sub>

> **Silent notifications are enabled by default**. The user does not need
> to approve your -- does not give permission to your app to use them,
> and you can just start using them without asking the user for
> permission.

> <sub>[From WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720?time=126)</sub>

**Remember** APNs is delivered to your users by APNs and not by your server. So your iOS code must send this token to your server. So the server can associate a given device token with the user. When you want to push to a certain user, your server just tells APNs to send a payload to a specific token. What's important to understand is that your server and APNs are two different things

The flow of it looks like this:

[image]

1. server/provider sends a payload to APNs
2. APNs send a notification to all target devices of a given account. e.g. your iPhone, Mac could both receive notifications for emails/messages.
3. Then your iPhone/Mac will deliver that message to the app. APNs don't directly send messages to your app. It sends it to the device. Then the iOS sends it to your app.

For more on this see docs [APNs Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) and [Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/)

---

To be able to **show** badges/alerts/sounds, you need to request *permission* from the user:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    
    guard error == nil else {
        //Display Error.. Handle Error.. etc..
        return
    }
    
    if granted {
        //Do stuff here..
        
        //Register for RemoteNotifications. Your Remote Notifications can display alerts now :)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    else {
        //Handle user denying permissions..
    }
}
```

**Question:** Do I need to request access once for local notifications and once for remote notifications?

No. Just write the snippet above and it will request access for *both* remote and local.

Now let's get to the tricky part :D

---

## Xcode Project + iPhone Settings

**Do I need to enable something to receive silent notifications?**

1. You must enable **Push Notifications** from your Xcode capabilities:

[image]

<sub>If you don't enable this, your app won't receive a token. And without a token, the server doesn't recognize you.</sub>

2. To be able to download stuff from the *background*, you need to enable: **remote notifications** from background modes.

To enable [backgroundModes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started), you can do it *either* using your **plist** or **Xcode capabilities**.

<sub>The reason you can do it, either way, is because plist is closer to your code and is the old way, perhaps it's there for legacy support. Xcode capabilities is the newer, easy way.</sub>

**plist:**

[image]

<sub>Item 0 is just an **index**, it's not the key of a dictionary (something you normally see in plist), the UIBackgroundModes is an `array` of Strings. The strings must only come from an *accepted value* from the [UIBackgroundModes Array](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10).</sub>

**Xcode Capabilities:**

Check the `Remote Notification` in **Xcode under background modes** as below:

[image]

If you don't do any of the above, then toggling off notifications with:

[image]

will kill **Remote & Local Notifications**

---

*However*, if you **do** enable background app refresh from plist or Xcode capabilities, then even with notifications turned off for the app, you will still receive silent notifications!

If the user wants to disable silent notifications, he would have to disable both notifications and disable 'background app refresh for your app / across the system.
To disable 'background app refresh' across your system, you have to do this:

[image]

Why am I saying all this? To explain to you that *settings* of silent and push notifications are different for the user and the restrictions for sending them are different. <s>For more, see [this moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720/?time=142) from the WWDC video</s>. See [here instead](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/720) (the previous link was dead):

> Silent notifications are enabled by default.
>
> The user does not need to approve your does not give permission to
> your app to use them, and you can just start using them without asking
> the user for permission.
>
> **But silent notifications are the mechanism behind background app
> refresh.**
>
> **At any point you know that the user can go in settings and disable
> them.**
>
> So you can't depend on them always being available.
>
> You don't know if the user the turn them off, and you are not getting
> a notification anymore.
>
> This also means that silent notifications are delivered with the best
> effort.
>
> That means that when the notification arrives on the user's device,
> the system is going to make some choices.
>
> It's going to use different signals from the device and from the user
> behavior, like power or the time of day to decide when it is a good
> time to deliver the notification and launch your app.
>
> It may try to save battery or it may try to match the user behavior
> and make the content available when the user is more likely to use it.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644343/is-silent-remote-notifications-possible-if-user-has-disabled-push-for-the-app).

**CAVEAT:** Even if you disable app background refresh and disable allow notifications, you can still receive silent notifications if your app is in FOREGROUND. If your app is in the background, it won't be delivered.

---

**Do I need to enable something to receive remote notifications?**

You just need to enable **Push Notifications** from your Xcode capabilities:

[image]

<sub>If you don't enable this, your app won't receive a token. And without a token, the server doesn't recognize you.</sub>

---

## APNs Payload structure

**Curious... Can you tell me what should my payload look like?**

I highly recommend you see Apple<sup>§</sup> [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html). It's very clear AND ALSO SEE [Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/). Basically platform makes an HTTP/2 call to APNs and sends the desired payload. Sending the correct headers is critical otherwise your notifications are not delivered to the devices!

**Thanks, but can you just tell me the important parts?**

uhhmm... OK, but just so you know this is from the link I just said:

For **Silent Notifications** there is a single criterion:

- The payload's `aps` dictionary must include the `content-available` key
  with a value of `1`.
- Per [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) you can send other fields

> If there are user-visible updates that go along with the background
> update, you can set the alert, sound, or badge keys in the aps
> dictionary, as appropriate.

A sample payload would look like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

acme1, acme2, or just some custom data! But for the `aps` key, you MUST follow Apple's structure, otherwise, it won't *map* correctly and you won't be able to read data correctly.

Note: I haven't verified this, but another engineer mentioned that if you have **provisional notifications** enabled then to ensure silent notifications are delivered you must include an alert field with an empty body. For example:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "alert" : {
          "body" : "",
        },
    },
}
```

For **User Notifications**:

You need an `alert` key inside your `aps`.

As an example:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

There is also a **third option** which I will discuss further down the answer.

As for what the fixed `aps` and `alert` dictionary keys are, see these [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

**OK, got it. What is `content-available`?**

Very simple. It's just a flag that tells your app that you need to wake up and download something because I have content available for download! For more info, see this [exact moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720?time=307).

By default the `content-available` flag is not included, i.e., by default the  notifications you send *won't* trigger `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` or do something in your app. It would just show the notification. If you want to wake up the app (to do something in the background), you need to include `content-available` and set it to `1`.

> §: If you're using **Firebase**, your payload structure and keys may be slightly different. For example, the key `content-available` is replaced by `content_available`. For more, see [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37899712/5175709).

---

**I know you told me that I can only download something into my app when I'm using silent notifications, but is there a way that I can also wake my app up in the background AND download something for remote notifications?**

Yes, but then similar to the silent notification, you must also set the `content-available` flag to 1, so it would know to wake up and download something. Otherwise, it would just pop and alert/badge/sound but won't download anything.

IMPORTANT NOTES:

- If your app has only silent notifications, just enable "push notifications" + "remote notifications" from capabilities and set `content-available` to `1` for each payload.
- If your app has only remote notifications, just enable "push notifications" from capabilities. There's nothing to do for the `content-available`.
- However, if you want your notifications to show an alert/badge/sound and also download something in the background, you must have both "remote notifications" and "push notifications" enabled + set `content-available` to `1`.

(THIRD OPTION)

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1 
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
        "acme1" : "bar",
        "acme2" : 42
}
```

<sub>[This moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/720?time=305) from WWDC video mentions the</sub>

To Quote the Apple Engineer:

> Now, you can in a **user** remote notification, you can set the same
> **content available** flag that you set in silent notifications, and that
> allows your app to have some time to download the content or update
> the content that it wants to be displayed so that when the user taps
> on the notification, your content is available. And the user sees what
> it does. This is a way to have a silent notification inside a user
> notifications like a summary.

---

## Notifications and iOS Application life-cycle

**I'm confused about remote notifications. I thought whenever I get a notification, my app becomes active in the background and downloads something. Can you explain?**

e.g. at this moment:

[image]

- Your iPhone has just received a remote notification with a body of "no sender". To receive this, WhatsApp ** doesn't** have to be running in the background, i.e., you don't need "Remote Notifications" enabled from BackgroundModes. You would still receive the notification even if your app was force-quit or suspended because the **process is managed by the OS, not the WhatsApp app**. However, if you want to be able to download the actual message or its image/video to WhatsApp (so that once your user opens WhatsApp, the video would be sitting there waiting for the user), well then you need your app to become active. To do so, you need `content-available : 1` and implement `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` .
- Similarly, if you disable cellular data for an app, you would still receive its notifications. However, by tapping on that notification, the user **won't** be able to make any *network requests* for that app. They would only be able to *open* the app.
- Or as for another similar scenario, if the server/access point you're connected to has restricted access for, say, WhatsApp, it would still allow you to receive the APNs notifications. However, by tapping on that notification, the user **won't** be able to make any *network requests* for that app. They would only be able to *open* the app.

**CAVEAT:** If the app was force-quit by the user, then while you do get the notification for the above-mentioned reasons, you can't do anything to bring the app out of its terminated state automatically (even if you had `content-available` set to `1`). None of your delegate methods would be hit. The *user* must open the app and only then your delegate methods will be reached.

---

## A note on reliability and APNs architecture:

Although notifications are heavily used to deliver the actual content to the app, they are somewhat NOT designed to *deliver* content to the app. Rather, they are designed to *notify* the user that "hey something new has arrived (a 2b message or a 50kb small image, or a 10MB image or a 2 GB video). Open the app if you like. By the way, here's a small piece of it (the actual message itself **if** it can fit, the title of the image or a thumbnail shown in the notification, a title of the video or a thumbnail shown in the video". For more, see [iOS APNs “best-effort” fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26302770/5175709). To repeat, you never download the 40MB attachment sent in the email. You just get notified of its existence. You send just enough (a thumbnail view of the attachment) so that the user is informed of what's new and can decide whether or not they need to open the app for more. When I was new to iOS, I thought you actually send the image/video through the push notification. You don't!

Specifically in the case of silent notifications:

> When a device receives a background notification, the system may hold
> and delay the delivery of the notification, which can have the
> following side effects:
>
> - When the system receives a new background notification, it discards the older notification and only holds the newest one.
> - If something force quits or kills the app, the system discards the held notification.
> - If the user launches the app, the system immediately delivers the held notification.
>    <sub>Pushing Background Updates to Your App [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)</sub>
> - APNs sends a limited number of silent notifications—notifications with the content-available key—per day. In addition, if the device has already exceeded its power budget for the day, silent notifications are not sent again until the power budget resets, which happens once a day. These limits are disabled when testing your app from Xcode. See Pushing Background Updates to Your App.

> <sub>[Troubleshooting tips for handling errors returned from ANPs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns)</sub>

Even for remote user notifications, the user may be off of the internet and this could cause expired content or APNs could throttle you if you're sending notifications too many or too quickly. See here again

Long story short the APNs and OS are King and you're beneath it. Hence you cannot rely on it to conform to your every command. Having that said it's super reliable in the sense that you see most messaging apps utilize it successfully.

### Addendum How to generate push notification certificate, `.p12` or `.pem` and how to test it all out?

Just see this [terrific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048689/5175709). It has the most number of screenshots I've ever seen.

Comment: "Even if you disable app background refresh & disable allow notifications, you can still receive silent notifications if your app is in FOREGROUND." I tried this with no success. Have you tried it and seen it work?

Comment: @JohnL. iLl have to test it and get back to you later. Not sure when, cuz I need to setup things to test it

Comment: hi, when i get the push notification ,the app should get active in background and do the task given in , ( like user's location update code or some other code ) ,- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler, but my app would not get active until user taps on the notification. how would i get this done while app is in background? i have followed everything which @Honey has said but no use.dose anyone know the solution for this ? i am using FCM for notification .

Comment: @Moxarth It's hard to assist you this way. Can you write a new question and then **show** us all your settings/payload/delegate methods? Also don't forget for FCM the key name is NOT `content-available` I believe it's `content_available`. For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40807397/5175709)

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised (at least in my case) when I realized my app was receiving silent notifications even if the user has turned off notifications. It not a critical feature, per guidelines, but it gets rid of a headache I thought I had. Thinking about it more, it makes sense since all the user is asking for is NOT to be notified, and he isn't. Just the app is.

Comment: `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`
I have one doubt when my application is in the foreground, this method gets called without tapping on it, so if I have to open a screen on tap only, this triggers that function. How to trigger a function when the app is in the foreground, the user receives a notification and tap on it.

Comment: This is the best response I've ever seen on SO. Thanks @Honey

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and comprehensive answer. If i am using 'content-available' along with remote notification(having alert), will iOS treat it as silent notification or remote notification?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz silent notifications are also remote notifications. Your question should be "will iOS treat it as silent notification or user notification". The answer is: it will treat it as **both** that is 1) because of `content-avaialble` app will get a callback upon receiving the notification  2) user will see a notification because of alert

Comment: @mfaani when both `content-available` and `alert`/`badge`/`sound` are used, is the notification still prioritized low by APNs? More specifically, do we still need to try to send no more than 2-3 messages per hour (I think this was the recommendation)? Or would showing an alert/badge/sound free us from that restriction?

Comment: @HakanSerce it's been a while...my 'gut feeling' is that: notifications will be delivered to the OS, users will see the notification with a high priority. Also the `apns-priority` header is important. But as for waking up the OS, I think for that you're rate limited — regardless of sending the alert or the apns-priority, but I could be wrong about this. I guess you have to try it out in the field and see...

Answer (score 8):

The push notification will let the user know that they receive a notification (Showing the notification popup for example). The silent notification will update, but the user won't get notified about it.
In any case, you can perform actions when notified with silent, just as if it was a push notification. The only difference is the user will not get notify with the popup notification.

With push notification:
[image]

With silent notification:
[image]

The difference is in the payload:

Push notification:

```
     aps {
       content-available: 1
       alert: {...}
     }
```

Silent notification:

```
    aps {
      content-available: 0
      alert: {...}
    }
```

And you have to set in **Capabilities** the background mode you choose.

Comment: push notification? Do you mean push = remote. Or push = remote + silent?

Comment: push = remote + silent. The only difference is that the silent dont notify the user with the popup. Anyway, this only happen when the app is in background. If the application is in foreground, the user never get notified with the popup.

Comment: is notification type (remote, silent) set up at my server before being sent? Or it is just a way iOS uses to categorize push notifications upon phone's status?

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. But I see **Push/Remote** notification in your answer, but in your comment **Push = Remote + silen**

Comment: both diagrams have same `content-available` = 1 though

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to say is that remote and silent are the same, the only difference is the popup notification while in background.
@tranvansang I get that image from Google, let me edit it

Comment: do you need to get permission from the user for **silent** notification?

Comment: @Honey Yes, you do (As far as I know)

Comment: you divided into Push/Remote and Silent. It make people (include me) confuse that Push and remote are same, and silent is different kind. Please edit your answer if you think it should be

Comment: why does [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) say "Include this key with a value of **1** to configure a silent notification". Isn't it exactly the opposite of what the image is saying?!

Comment: "content-available: 1" means silent. It actually means, there's content available on the server, go connect with it to download the content data.  So, it wakes up the app to do so, without letting the user know what actually happens.

Comment: @AndaluZ correct. Additionally you could also have `content-available` set to `1` and then at the same time have an alert sent to you. See the 'third Option' from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302369/5175709). (This answer is 100% wrong and confusing)

Answer (score 1):

Silent push notification reaches device, user does not know anything about the notification but his app gets the notification and app will be given some time to download new content and present it to the user, regardless to the state of the app (i.e. running or not running)

Remote push notification method is called only when your app is running. If app is suspended or not running, then the system wakes up or launches your app and puts it into the background running state before calling the method.
This method is intended for showing the updated content to the user.When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the specified completion handler block. If the handler is not called in time, your app will be suspended.

For more technical details, you can go through this links:

[Apple Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

[Silent Notifications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_silent_notification.html)

Comment: hi, when i get the push notification ,the app should get active in background and do the task given in , ( like user's location update code or some other code ) ,- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler, but my app would not get active until user taps on the notification. how would i get this done while app is in background?.dose anyone know the solution for this ? i am using FCM for notification .