# silent push notifications for opted out users

Tags: ios, push-notification, remote-notifications, silent-notification

I would like to send a silent notification to my app users, to refresh the content.

I have read various articles on sending silent notification to opted out users. But, how do we do it? Most opted out users don't have device push tokens. How do you ping a device to send the silent push payload?

We currently use push tokens for opted in users to send a remote notification. But if iOS 8 and beyond allows to send silent notification to all the app users even if they are opted out, how do I send them without a token?

Comment: Rephrase your question please. It's not clear. Are you asking how can you send silent notifiation to opted out users...as in users who clicked on the "Don't Allow" notifications?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly I would like to understand

Comment: For silent notifications you don't need user's permission. You can register for their token silently. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369). You only need permission if you want to show badge,alert or sound ie if it's a local notification or a remote notification

Answer (score -1):

There are no possibility to send remote notifications to devices that are not registered with a device token. Also you can not send any notification if user doesnt allow the app to receive remote notifications.

Comment: iOS 8 and beyond allows you to send a silent notification to all the users even though the user has opted out of notifications. These silent notifications are meant to update the app content by firing the app in the background.

Comment: You can also check it here : https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/watch-list-ios-8-opt-in-changes