# iOS with Firebase notification, all not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What ever I do the notification is not received.
Sending to Android is going fine, sending to iOS is a failure

I am sending from Firebase Console

I am not receiving foreground or background notification

here is the AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        }

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as? MessagingDelegate
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]

        //create the notificationCenter
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            //FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }
        print("Registration succeeded! Token: ", token)

        let topicName = "/topics/ChaclateOnMobile"
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: topicName)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Registration failed! \(error)")
    }

    // Firebase notification received
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
        print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

        let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let body : String = d["body"] as! String
        let title : String = d["title"] as! String
        print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
        self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)

    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
        print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }

    func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    // Firebase ended here
```

}

Comment: Check if you are using the correct token for sending notifications.

Comment: 1. Have enabled **Push notifications** from Xcode Capabilities? 2. Have you enabled **Remote notifications** from your background modes (also in Xcode capabilities)? For a complete list of what you need to do see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you are using the correct `token` for sending notifications.
2. Have you `registered` your app to receive `Push Notifications`?
3. Check if you have implemented proper methods in `AppDelegate.`

When the app is `not running`, the notification is received in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Add this to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your code:

```
if let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject]
{
    //Your code
}
```

When your app is in `background/foreground`, the notification is received in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    //Your code
}
```