# Can't receive push notifications using Ionic Cloud on iOS

Tags: swift, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, apple-push-notifications

I'm using ionic's cloud push notification service for both android and iOS, along with phonegap-plugin-push. Since i'm using my own server-side authentcation and not ionic's, I have it configured so that a user's authentication token is registered depending on whether or not they're logged in, and saved when they log in (unregistered when they log out).

App.module:

```
const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID',
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': 'SENDER_ID',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true,

      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

instead of making push a provider in app module, I made an injectable service that can be used across components. The main app component subscribes to the notifications, while my login and logout components tell it whether or not to register and save them.

```
export class NotificationService{

    token: PushToken;
    registered: boolean;


    constructor(public push: Push){

    }



  checkLogin(status){
    if(!status){
      this.push.register().then((pushT: PushToken) => {

      this.token = pushT;
      console.log('token saved:'+ this.token);
    });
  }
  }


saveToken(){
  this.push.saveToken(this.token);
  console.log('token saved');
  this.registered = true;
  this.startListening();
}
deleteToken(status){
  if(status){
    this.push.unregister().then(function(){
      console.log('token deleted');
      return true;
    })
  }
}

startListening(){
  if(this.registered){
  return this.push.rx.notification()
  .subscribe((msg) => {
    alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
  });
}}
getToken(){
  return this.token.token;
}

}
```

I have my sender ID for GCM configured in config.xml and ionic cloud, and my APNS certificate is saved in ionic cloud. So far this works perfectly on android. On iOS it registers the token and saves to the database, but testing on Ionic cloud my iPhone doesn't receive any notifications. Any thoughts?

Comment: show us your code where you receive/manage the notifications for the iPhone device...

Comment: That's all of it (startlistenting()). that function is also called in app component.

Comment: It seems that you need to learn A LOT of basics: See the 3 links provided at last line of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369). Then go back and read the answer itself. It will help you get a better understanding.

Comment: I mean i checked everything off in xcode, and it works on android, and like i said it generates a token and saves. the problem is that it doesn't receive anything. I made a function push.on('notification') but it wouldn't allow it.

Comment: I dont know how to help you sorry. Follow another tutorial on notifications.

Comment: works fine now. Turns out we just didn't use the right certificate for APNS.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?. (I've worked with push notifications a lot...but never arrived at a project where they were they didn't even have their certificates ready)

Comment: we had our certificate ready, we just didn't have push notifications in our developer certificate to allow it in the first place.