# How to check Push Notification is Receive in background mode in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

how to get Push Notification Massage data without tap an Push notification Alert in notification bar in objective c

Comment: What do you mean without tapping? Are you talking about *silent* notifications? If so I recommend you to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code i hope it will help you

```
    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        NSLog(@"%@", [userInfo description]);
        if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
            {
              // Write your code for Background State
             }
        else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
           {
              // Write your code here for Active state        
           }
        else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
           {
              // Write your code for Inactive State

           }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get push notification message without tapping on notification alert only if you implement VoIP push notification service.
[VoIP Push Service]

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html

If you use Apple PushKit framework you will get message data in following delegate:

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type { NSDictionary *userInfo = payload.dictionaryPayload;NSLog("Your JSON here: %@",userInfo);
}
```