# Does setting "Content-available" : "1" actually launches the app in background if app is not really opened?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I was going to Content-available flag in push notification payload and get doubt over statment which says that if set to "1" iOS will launch the application in background.
Lets assume app is never tapped and opened. So does this mean if recevied this flag app will be actually launched in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369).

But no it won't work. Why? Because you need to launch the app at least once so you get a token. Without a token the server can't differentiate between your device and thousands of other users.

Answer (score 0):

For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the notification’s payload must include the content-available key with its value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in the background (or **launches it into the background**) and calls the app delegate’s application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: method. Your implementation of that method should download the relevant content and integrate it into your app.

Apple documentation : [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)