# processing push data when app closed, app open and app in background

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-push-notifications, xcode8

I have the following fund in app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print notification payload data
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")


    let dictPayload = data as NSDictionary

    if let data = dictPayload.value(forKey: "aps") as? NSDictionary {
        let link = data.value(forKey: "Link") as? String
        print("link: \(link!)")

        UserDefaults.standard.set(link, forKey: "link_from_push")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

Basically, the push notification contains data with a link in an app. When user opens app, I need to log user on automatically, do a bunch of stuff and then open the link.

My code works fine when app is open. I receive the push, extract the link no problem.

On the other hand when app is closed or in the background, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not being called, and i am guessing it isn't being called because UserDefaults.standard forKey: "link_from_push") is not being set.

How can I set the value of link as UserDefaults.standard forKey:"link_from_push" when app is in the background or completely closed. Is there another method I need to use for that instead of didReceiveRemoteNotification

This is not a duplicate since the answer in the question: didReceiveRemoteNotification not called , iOS 10  addresses obj c and not swift, and the answer given for swift did not work.

please help

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification not called , iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10)

Comment: not a duplicate.

Comment: Are you setting content-available = 1 in your push payload?  If not then the push will not be delivered to your app when it is suspended.

Comment: I have not. will my didReceiveRemoteNotification work as is when app is closed if I add this setting?

Comment: @Paulw11 see *his* comment. Johny you must use the AT sign if there are more than 1 people commenting others Paulw won't know. Johny you're using the **deprecated** function. you must instead use: [`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application). Additionally as Paul said you must set the `content-available` to `1`.  For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369)