# didreceiveremotenotification Not Called In Foreground When Notifications Disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications

If user does not give permission for notifications, `didreceiveremotenotification` is not called when a remote notification is received while the app is in the foreground. I do not want to use a silent notification because when the app is in the background and user allows notifications, I want the alert notification to appear. But when in the foreground, I want to handle the notification data myself, even if the user has opted out of notifications.

How can this be achieved?

**EDIT:** I see that device registration token is not created when user disables notifications. But how would silent notifications work then?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following SO answer: [What is difference between remote notification and silent notification in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42275137)

In short, to achieve what I wanted, I needed to enable Remote Notifications in the Bacground Modes of plist. Then I was able to register a token even if the user opted out of receiving notifications.

Comment: I'm still confused of what you wanted to do, and if something of my answer was wrong. Can you clarify. Because I did mention what you said in your 2nd paragraph. Or is that you did this but it didn't work?

Comment: @Honey Did you mean to post this in response to my comment to your answer in the following thread?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#comment81185575_42302369