# Xamarin.Forms iOS PushNotification when App is closed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to receive push notifications under iOS, even when the app is closed (force closed)?

I only receive Push Notifications when the app is open or active in the background.

How do other apps realize this, for example: WhatsApp?

Comment: Are you debugging the application? If so, try to deploy it as a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it

Review the "Discussion" section: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

WhatsApp is a **VoIP application** and uses `PushKit` which is different then using the normal APNS notifications.

Long story short; *unless* your app is an VoIP provisioned/entitled app, once the user force quits the app, the app will not be restarted by iOS and thus you will not receive APNS notifications until the user restarts their iDevice or manually launches your app via Springboard.

Comment: So there is no possibility to receive Push Notifications until the app is declared as VoIP App? What if this functionality (VoIP) is not available, would Apple reject it?

Comment: If you are requesting VoIP entitlement, then yes, it needs to be a VoIP app otherwise Apple would reject it (and you would also need to implement PushKit)

Comment: @SushiHangover, I don't think so. Once app registered APNS, no matter whether it's on foreground or background or closed. It can receive notification from Apple. I think it's from system not your own app.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT the iDevice/iOS will receive the APNS notifications, BUT, since the user "force-closed" the app, iOS will not restart it automatically nor call `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and the notifications are discarded. This is by design in iOS in order to prevent malicious/spam/buggy apps from re-spawning over and over.

Comment: @SushiHangover I know notification will not restart or open app, also can't trigger `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`. But when app is on background or closed, it can also receive notification at notification window then when we tap it on the window, the event will be called. Only when app is on foreground, notification can fire this event automatically.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT ? That event fires on the background also, again assuming the app was not force closed. If the user selects a notification, that is a manually launch invitation to iOS just as if the user tapped the app's icon on Springboard, but in terms of "background" silent, content-based, or fetch notification, your app will not receive those after a force-close.

Comment: @SushiHangover OK, the feature what you said is about Silent Notification. But what about Remote Notification? iOS contains several types of notifications, also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios) for more details.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT That is a great SO answer and in terms of a "Remote" notification, yes iOS will present the notification to the user, but your app will never receive the details (if any) when the user selects it since the app was force-closed and thus none of the UIApplicationDelegate methods will be called until the user manually launches the app or reboots the device, which is covered in that answer by the last "CAVEAT:" statement. iOS respects that if a user force-closed the app and will not restart the app without an explicit intent.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, just as what I said above. App will only show a notification not trigger this event in this way. But when we tap the notification to open our app not through icon, we can get some details from `NSDictionary options` if the app is closed. But what I truly means is: App can receive APNS from closed state.