# Firebase push notification working for Android but for ios only working from Firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification

I have completed the steps in the Firebase website for push notifications for ios and Android. For Android everything works fine but for ios I can only receive push notifications sent through the Firebase console, not from my server side code. Any idea what could be going wrong? I researched the issue and came across an outdated solution for Firebase configuration but am wondering if there is something more recent. Thanks a lot!

This is the link where I got the instructions for setting up the service. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Here is my Swift code for notifications:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("***** MY FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}


}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
}


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
// [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

Comment: you have to show the links and *tell* us what you tried. I may be thinking of 9 steps but you maybe thinking of only 4 steps :). Also see [steps to configure iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302369/5175709)

Answer (score 1):

Can we see what your notification's structure looks like? I had this same issue and needed to add `priority: high` to work on iOS.

Comment: @AndraAvram please check this as the right answer then.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works. The problem was the backend code.

Comment: Hi can you explain little bit more where you had issue? I have the same problem. I'm using Firebase cloud functions and notifications work for Android but on iOS they don't work. Thanks

Comment: how did you modify your backend can share something with me, please