# is there a callback from Firebase Cloud Messaging to indicate that a message is received?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

from the documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive),  there are two methods to receive a push notification. but as the comment say, it is only fired when the user tap the notification when app is in the background.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)

  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

what I want is, whenever a push notification comes, then I want to do some action no matter if the user tap the push notification or not, in the background or in the foreground. so I need a callback whenever a message is received

in Android I can do it in `onMessageReceived` callback

```
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        
    }
```

is there any equivalent callback like that in iOS ? I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a silent notification to iOS app by specifying `content_available` in the notification payload. When it is set to true, the notification will wake your app in the background and you can handle the notification in `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` delegate method.

You can find more about [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app).

```
"to" : "[token]",
"content_available": true,
"priority": "high",
"data" : {
  "key1" : "abc",
  "key2" : abc
}
```

Comment: does the callback  still getting called if the user turn off our app push notification in iOS system settings ?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled by default and it doesn't need user permission. But the user can disable `background app refresh` from settings and the system will suppress the notifications thereafter.  As explained in the link provided in the above answer, `the system may throttle the delivery of background notifications if the total number becomes excessive`. Here's a detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42302369/5443937