# When in iOS applicationDidEnterBackground called immediately after applicationDidBecomeActive?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

in our app we are logging (with an external analytics service) every time the user open our app.
However, we have noticed that there are many weird app sessions (almost 15% of total sessions).

Following the device timestamp of the events, the following methods are called:

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)

applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)

viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) // App Splash Screen

applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
```

Looking at the timestamp, from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  to `applicationDidEnterBackground`  there is just a very short delay (<1 sec).

Our hypothesis is that the system sometimes wakes up the app without it being actually opened and "seen" by the user. But we can't find any docs about this kind of use case, and we can't reproduce ourself the issue.
Did someone have experienced something similar?

**EDIT**:
I want to add that these suspicious sessions are often (but not always) linked to an app update.

Comment: It could be when the user reacts to a phone call, timer or alarm banner. I’m just guessing but maybe when the banner is dismissed the application “becomes active” but almost immediately the action takes over and your app is sent to the background

Comment: That's a possibility. However, there are too many sessions to be just phone call. Also, all the phone call should be between the app launch and the splash screen.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez the app doesn't get launched when user receives a notification, it's all handled at the OS level — unless push notification has `content-available: 1` then it will wake up the app too with [this callback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application). But _usually_ you don't send that flag with a notification that has alerts. Because the flag is meant to make the notification silent. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/4230236) for more

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure...

I suppose if app wasn't user terminated nor suspended but was just put out of memory because other apps needed the memory, then almost a launch options can wake the app up if needed. Some examples:

- geofence
- interaction with push notification's actions. Example if you have [userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) implemented...
- silent notification
- background app refresh

Take a look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey) and see what launch options are possible for your app. I'm not sure if all of them can actually launch the app or what...

If you want more visibility into this, then make sure for future you log the launchoptionskey that caused the app to get launched...

Comment: We completely remove the background capabilities of the app from the plist but the problem persisted. I don't know if 3rd party libraries can override that "setting".

Comment: @user1305336 That’s odd then. I don’t think a third party can, I mean, they can request for it, but main app has appropriate key-value pairs it its plist.

Answer (score 0):

You need more info - I would extend your logging to dump the `launchOptions` dictionary in

`application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`

Looking at [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey), there are a lot of options which may be involved. Note, as the [help](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) says: *The contents of this dictionary may be empty in situations where the user launched the app directly*

```
 if let lop = launchOptions { 
   let toLog = lop.map{"\($0.0.rawValue) \($0.1)"}.joined(separator:"\n")
   // log the options
...}
```

I did have an idea this might be related to previewing in AppSwitcher but that doesn't seem to trigger `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, unless you actually bring the app to the front. Maybe some split-screen stuff on iPad? It feels like the app is being invoked in a context where it can't get past the launch screen.